# How can I include non-argument text between @params in `roxygen2`?

Tags: r, documentation, roxygen2

I want to put subheadings *inside* my Arguments block between argument definitions. In regular Rd, this looks like the following:

```
\arguments{
  \item{x}{description of x}

Text outside any argument

  \item{y}{description of y}
}
```

When using `roxygen2`, any text between a `@param` tag and the next tag is included in the argument description, so something like the following doesn't work:

```
@param x description of x

Text outside any argument

@param y description of y
```

This simply puts the text inside the definition for `x`. Is there a way to "escape" the `@param` tag while keeping the text inside the `\arguments{}` block?

Answer (score 0):

Not very clean but you can use `\cr` to break lines and then format the text to look like an "Arguments subsection". This seems to work with `pkgdown` but it feels like a hack.

Also, I don't know how to remove the indent before "If you need this", `\noindent` doesn't appear to be supported.

`hello.R`:

```r
#' Title
#'
#' @param x hi
#' \cr \cr
#' \strong{If you need this}
#'
#' @param y hi again
#'
#' @export

hello <- function(x, y) {
  print("Hello, world!")
}
```

How it's rendered in RStudio:

[image]